# Upload file to Google Drive after downloading it from URL

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api

Greetings! I am now writing a little script for my spreadsheet and I have the last piece of puzzle remaining unsolved.
I want to download a file (or get all the file data) from a specific URL and then upload it to Google Drive (or create a file with those file data). I believe I can do that but how? May anyone help me please?
If this doesn't work, then I would have to set up a server with my computer. Send a request from by spreadsheet script to my computer. Let my computer run a script and download the file and save it into a specific folder. Let Google Drive sync the file... This is totally possible but is there a simpler way to achieve what I want?
Thank you in advance!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var file = DriveApp.createFile(response.getBlob()).setName(filename);
```

I've written a more complete script/webapp for this purpose. The full source-code is available at [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/denilsonsa/8134679+.) and at [Google Apps Script](https://script.google.com/d/1Ye-OEn1bDPcmeKSe4gb0YSK83RPMc4sZJt79SRt-GRY653gm2qVUptoE/edit), feel free to study and use that code. There is also a [live version](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzvhbHS4hnWPVBDHjQzZHA0qWq0GR-6hY7TbYsNto6hZ0MeAFZt/exec).

Comment: Hello,

i'm trying to use this solution to download torrent files i get in my email. I successfully obtained url (string), folder id and filename, but i get the following error from this script:
Exception: No valid argument:url

any ideas ? please

if i paste url in explorer, the file gets downloaded...

Comment: Your question should be a new question on this site, not just a comment here. Make sure it is descriptive enough of what you are trying to do, and how you are trying it. A code snippet will probably help. Still, that's a new question, not just a comment here.

Answer (score 0):

Use [UrlFetch Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/) to get the data from the URL and [Drive Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/) to store this data on Google Drive

Comment: Thanks :D
but isn't UrlFetch return only the source code of a URL?

Comment: UrlFetch is returning whatever the resource identified by the URL is willing to serve.  For HTTP-URLs its often HTML-code but the are lots of binary encoded (PNG, GIF) images as well. UrlFetch does the same request as your browser or a local command line tool like `wget`